# Recovering the data of a column of record of an Excel sheet in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retrieve the data (registration numbers) of a column of record from an Excel sheet on another Excel sheet when the name columns are the same.

That is to say on the "Convocation" sheet there is

```
Matric Apellido         Nombre  Avión
12     Burrow           Irving  F15     
42     Nelson           Howard  A10
18     Krings           Jack    F18    
10     Mitaux-Maurouard Guy     Rafale
```

And in the sheet "RECAP" I have

```
Apellido         Nombre ...
Nelson           Howard ...
Burrow           Irving ...
Mitaux-Maurouard Guy   
Krings           Jack   ...
```

Y me gustaría

```
Apellido Nombre ... Matric
Nelson   Howard ... 42
Burrow   Irving ... 12  
Krings   Jack   ... 18
```

I tried :

```
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Matriculas As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Need the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library in Tools-> References

    'We store the sheet with everything in an array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Convocation")
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
    End With

    'We assume that the registration is in column A and surnames B and C
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if we find empty values we leave the loop
        If Not Matriculas.Exists(arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3)) Then 'we check that the combo of surnames is not duplicated
            Matriculas.Add arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3), arr(i, 1) 'we keep in the dictionary the combo of surnames with their registration
        Else 'If the person could have more than 1 license plate then:
            Matriculas(arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3)) = Matriculas(arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3)) & ", " & arr(i, 1) 'we add the others separated by ","
        End If
    Next i

    'We store the sheet with everything in an array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RECAP")
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
        'We assume that the surnames are in columns A and B, and the registration in C
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if we find empty values we leave the loop
            arr(i, 3) = Matriculas(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2)) 'here we assign the registration stored in the dictionary according to surnames
        Next i
        .UsedRange.Value = arr 'we return the array to the sheet
    End With

End Sub
```

But when I compile I have this error: Sub or Function undefined. I have put the code in `Microsoft Excel Objects` that contains all the sheets, in particular in `ThisWorkbook`.

## Edit: I know my problem

My problem wasn't with the first line but with `Ubond`. When I get rid of it I don't have errors anymore. But they are necessary for the loops.

Comment: What line gives you the error?

Comment: @DarXyde The first one

Comment: It runs for me... had to add the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library, but other than that... works. Maybe you have something else in a module or one of the other sheets that causes the error?

Comment: @ThePassenger Would a non VBA solution work for you?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data on CONVOCATION sheet is like:

[image]

And sheet RECAP is:

[image]

To get the number from field `MAtric` I've used an array formula:

`=INDEX(Convocation!$A$2:$A$5;MATCH(A2&B2;Convocation!$B$2:$B$5&Convocation!$C$2:$C$5;0))`

> Because this is an array formula, it must be inserted with
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work!

**NOTE:** About your data, this formula will work as long as all `Apellido` and `Nombre` are different between rows. If at any moment you have 2 clients (2 rows) with same `Apellido` and `Nombre` then the formula won't work properly, because yoo would need a third field to differentiate both clientes between them (maybe a second `Apellido`).

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**UPDATE:** In case the formula finds nothing, it will throw an error, but you can trap it with an `IFERROR`, so the ideal formula would be:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Convocation!$A$2:$A$5;MATCH(A2&B2;Convocation!$B$2:$B$5&Convocation!$C$2:$C$5;0));"Not found!")`

> Because this is an array formula, it must be inserted with
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work!

**UPDATE 2:** You can download a sample here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kQ0boXYl7nvkTef62zVg9Jw7raOqgsuf

Comment: I'm adapting it to the actual sheet at the moment. Thank you ! Yet RECAP don't have the `matric` at the beginning

Comment: @ThePassenger Reading your question, sheet RECAP got `matric` at third column (column C in my image) is that not right?

Comment: In the end yes. That's what I'm looking for

Comment: And that's what I did. In my image, you can see `matric` numbers in column C. The second image shows that. How should it be? The only different is that my data is sorted different that your example, but it works properly.

Comment: I only have `Not found!` Do you know how I can do a step by step debug so I can know where it failed ?

Comment: Yes, on the ribbon, on the formulas tab, there is a button called `Evaluate` that should allow you to do that, but anyways let me upload a sample to Gdrive and you can download that Excel File and see how I applied the formulas

Comment: @ThePassenger Download https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kQ0boXYl7nvkTef62zVg9Jw7raOqgsuf